# Use http Error(runnable, locked to thread)

Tags: go

I am replacing the usage of JDBC Template with Jooq. For example, to batch update entities in a database. Against this I am running unit tests that use Quickperf annotations, as @ExpectUpdate.

The batch size in Jooq configuration is set to 100. Now, if I update 650 entities, I would expect 7 queries (650/100) to be executed. However, Quickperf tells me:

```
goroutine 3133262 [select]:
runtime.gopark(0xc013e1df90?, 0x2?, 0xd8?, 0xdd?, 0xc013e1df24?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:363 +0xd6 fp=0xc013e1dd90 sp=0xc013e1dd70 pc=0x85b496
runtime.selectgo(0xc013e1df90, 0xc013e1df20, 0xc00262e900?, 0x0, 0xc01adf8300?, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:328 +0x7dc fp=0xc013e1ded0 sp=0xc013e1dd90 pc=0x86983c
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc00607a240)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2392 +0xf5 fp=0xc013e1dfc8 sp=0xc013e1ded0 pc=0xad4c35
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn.func6()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1752 +0x26 fp=0xc013e1dfe0 sp=0xc013e1dfc8 pc=0xad1726
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 +0x1 fp=0xc013e1dfe8 sp=0xc013e1dfe0 pc=0x8865c1
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1752 +0x1791

——————————
goroutine 3133490 [runnable, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x887ea0, 0xc0300abac0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:158 +0x4a fp=0xc025267a50 sp=0xc025267a18 pc=0x8248ea
syscall.SyscallN(0x7ffab1585000?, {0xc025267ae8?, 0x3?, 0x0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:557 +0x109 fp=0xc025267ac8 sp=0xc025267a50 pc=0x8830c9
syscall.Syscall(0xc025267b28?, 0x851a25?, 0xd003e6?, 0xc025267b48?, 0x88030d?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:495 +0x3b fp=0xc025267b10 sp=0xc025267ac8 pc=0x882ddb
syscall.Closesocket(0x880de5?)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1343 +0x5c fp=0xc025267b58 sp=0xc025267b10 pc=0x8d557c
internal/poll.(*FD).destroy(0xc013f40a00)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_windows.go:373 +0x9a fp=0xc025267b80 sp=0xc025267b58 pc=0x8f4bfa
internal/poll.(*FD).decref(0x219eb330b48?)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:213 +0x53 fp=0xc025267ba0 sp=0xc025267b80 pc=0x8f2833
internal/poll.(*FD).Close(0xc013f40a00)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_windows.go:395 +0x69 fp=0xc025267bd0 sp=0xc025267ba0 pc=0x8f4ce9
net.(*netFD).Close(0xc013f40a00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:37 +0x38 fp=0xc025267c00 sp=0xc025267bd0 pc=0x9f3538
net.(*conn).Close(0xc02d6ae218)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:207 +0x45 fp=0xc025267c30 sp=0xc025267c00 pc=0xa03d85
net/http.(*persistConn).closeLocked(0xc01d7acb40, {0xdebaa0, 0xc00005abe0})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2714 +0x130 fp=0xc025267cb8 sp=0xc025267c30 pc=0xad64f0
net/http.(*persistConn).close(0xc00476e7d8?, {0xdebaa0?, 0xc00005abe0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2699 +0xb0 fp=0xc025267d10 sp=0xc025267cb8 pc=0xad62f0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2061 +0x2d fp=0xc025267d40 sp=0xc025267d10 pc=0xad40ed
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc01d7acb40)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2236 +0xab6 fp=0xc025267fc8 sp=0xc025267d40 pc=0xad38b6
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn.func5()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1751 +0x26 fp=0xc025267fe0 sp=0xc025267fc8 pc=0xad1786
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 +0x1 fp=0xc025267fe8 sp=0xc025267fe0 pc=0x8865c1
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1751 +0x173e

—————————
goroutine 3117448 [semacquire]:
runtime.gopark(0x3?, 0xc00a0f1c20?, 0x40?, 0x2b?, 0xc00a0f1c20?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:363 +0xd6 fp=0xc00a0f1bd8 sp=0xc00a0f1bb8 pc=0x85b496
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:369
runtime.semacquire1(0xc00ceb3544, 0x80?, 0x3, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:150 +0x20f fp=0xc00a0f1c40 sp=0xc00a0f1bd8 pc=0x86a92f
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0x0?, 0x0?, 0xc02eb7f680?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:77 +0x25 fp=0xc00a0f1c70 sp=0xc00a0f1c40 pc=0x881b85
sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow(0xc00ceb3540)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:171 +0x165 fp=0xc00a0f1cc0 sp=0xc00a0f1c70 pc=0x89e545
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:90
net/http.(*Transport).removeIdleConn(0xc01defbcd8?, 0xdebaa0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1096 +0x56 fp=0xc00a0f1d10 sp=0xc00a0f1cc0 pc=0xacc2b6
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2062 +0x3b fp=0xc00a0f1d40 sp=0xc00a0f1d10 pc=0xad40fb
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc02ce15e60)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2236 +0xab6 fp=0xc00a0f1fc8 sp=0xc00a0f1d40 pc=0xad38b6
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn.func5()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1751 +0x26 fp=0xc00a0f1fe0 sp=0xc00a0f1fc8 pc=0xad1786
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 +0x1 fp=0xc00a0f1fe8 sp=0xc00a0f1fe0 pc=0x8865c1
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1751 +0x173e
```

Comment: You did not ask a question ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.